# How to loop throough fields in a database and find the empty ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to download a `.pdf` document from the external database [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) using an `HTML` link on a user interface.

The problem I have is that not always some of the fields inside `Contentful` require a `pdf` document and when there is no document to download the filed remains empty and the developer-tools throws an error. Because of that, the compilation stops and I can't `sudo npm start`.

**The problem:** How can I write a loop that skips empty fields in a database, in this case a `Contentful` beckend?

The file path is contained in: `ship.projectnotes.fields.file.url` as shown below:

```
import Client from '../Contentful';


class Sidebar extends React.Component {
state = {
    ships: []
};

async componentDidMount() {
    let response = await Client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'cards'
    });
    const ships = response.items.map((item) => {
        const {
            name,
            slug,
            projectnotes
        } = item.fields;
        return {
            name,
            slug,
            projectnotes
        };
    });

    this.setState({
        ships
    });
}


getFilteredShips = () => {
    // operations .......
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="map-sidebar">
            {this.props.activeShipTypes}
            <pre>
                {this.getFilteredShips().map((ship) => {
                    console.log(ship);

                    return (
                        <Card className="mb-2">
                            <CardImg />
                            <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle>
                                    <h3 className="thick">{ship.name}</h3>
                                </CardTitle>
                                <Row style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
                                    <div className="buttoncontainer">
                                        <div className="btn btn-cards">
                                            <a className="buttonLink" ship.projectnotes.fields.file.url} download>
                                                Project Notes
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Row>

                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    );
                })}
            </pre>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Sidebar;
```

I can confirm that I am reading correctly the name of the field from `Contentful`:

[image: field]

**What I have done so far:**

1) I was able to implement the link to the document but after I started using the external container Contentful, the pdf is not downloadable, contrarily to what I was hoping. The problem is that there is an empty field as unhandled problem and don't know how to take care of that.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .hasOwnProperty('fieldName') to safely check to see if an object has the property you require. So in your case you should be able to add a simple if statement to check to see if the field 'file' exits in your loop.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

```
import Client from '../Contentful';


    class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let response = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'cards'
        });
        const ships = response.items.map((item) => {
            const {
                name,
                slug,
                projectnotes
            } = item.fields;
            return {
                name,
                slug,
                projectnotes
            };
        });

        this.setState({
            ships
        });
    }


    getFilteredShips = () => {
        // operations .......
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="map-sidebar">
                {this.props.activeShipTypes}
                <pre>
                    {this.getFilteredShips().map((ship) => {
                        console.log(ship);
                        // lets add a check here you can change it to suit
                        if(ship.projectnotes.fields.hasOwnProperty('file')) {
                        return (
                            <Card className="mb-2">
                                <CardImg />
                                <CardBody>
                                    <CardTitle>
                                        <h3 className="thick">{ship.name}</h3>
                                    </CardTitle>
                                    <Row style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
                                        <div className="buttoncontainer">
                                            <div className="btn btn-cards">
                                                <a className="buttonLink" ship.projectnotes.fields.file.url} download>
                                                    Project Notes
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </Row>

                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        );
                      } else {
                         // return no render or what ever here
                         return null
                      }
                    })}
                </pre>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }

    export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reading the question. Almost!! Something is happening. I now have an error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined`. That means that, that entry is empty, meaning there is no `.pdf` document loaded in the database. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/F6RCnAX.png). As you see is `undefined`. So it does not still compile but I think that could be a good clue. Any idea?